# Not receiving any Webhooks

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In Meta for developers:

- I have a properly configured an app having a webhook for Page / ratings
- I am able to hit my endpoint fine
- The test button in the Webhooks page within the dashboard works and I see the invocation of my endpoint via logs.

In business.facebook.com where we manage all our facebook pages

- For a particular account I have assigned the above app (Settings > Accounts > App)
- This account has been assigned this app for a couple months now
- I have never received a recommendations post to my webhook, and there have been many recommendation entries since assigning the app

Any suggestions to why I never get a ratings / recommendation / reviews webhook?

Pictures added that outline what I have described here

[image]

[image]

[image]